# Evaluating $\oint_C{z^{-\frac{1}{2}}}e^{iz}dz$ to derive Fresnel Integrals.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to solve the integral $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}sin(u^2)du$(Fresnel Integral). I made some progress in this regard, but I had some doubts as to how to proceed from then on.

**Here is the approach i used**:

1. Let x=$u^2$ $\implies dx=2udu \implies du=\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx}{2}$, where the limits remain same. Thus $$I=1/2*\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}sin(x)dx$$
2. From here I consider $\oint_C{z^{-\frac{1}{2}}}e^{iz}dz$;  where C is [image: the contour:]

$C_1=[Re^{i\theta}|0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}]$; a quarter circle of radius R, $C_2=[iy|R\le y\le r ]$; along the Imaginary axis, $C_3=[re^{i\theta}|\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le0]$; quarter circle of radius r ,$C_4=[x|r\le x\le R ]$

Now, I have considered C to be broken into $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$, where these paths are also labeled in the diagram above.

3. As $z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}$ is analytic in the region described by C, we have that $$\oint_C{z^{-\frac{1}{2}}}e^{iz}dz=0;[Cauchy's Theorem]$$
4. From Here I get the following: $$\int_{C_1}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz+\int_{C_2}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz+\int_{C_3}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz+\int_{C_4}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz=0$$
   where $C_1, C_3$ are along the quarter circles of radii R and r respectively, and $C_2,C_4$ are along the coordinate axes. Now we would let $r\rightarrow0, R\rightarrow\infty$ in hopes of recovering our integral.

*This brings me to my question*:

a) How do I show that $\int_{C_1}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz=\int_{C_3}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz=0$ in the above limit? I tried using the Estimation Lemma to derive: $$|\int_{C_1}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz|\le \int_{C_1}|z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}|=\frac{\pi}{2}R*\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}dz $$ [As $C_1$ is a quarter circle of radius R, z=R on C] However in the limit R$\rightarrow\infty$, my integral doesn't tend to 0.
However, using the same procedure on $C_3$, I get that: $$|\int_{C_1}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz|\le \int_{C_1}|z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}|=\frac{\pi}{2}r*\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}dz $$  then in the limit r$\rightarrow0$ this integral **does** tend to 0.

b) Why couldn't the estimation lemma be used for the quarter circle of radius R then? How would i show that $\int_{C_1}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{iz}dz=0$?

c) Jordan's Lemma seems like the perfect candidate to prove that the above integral is 0, however, as i deal with contours of quarter-circle like shape I cannot use this Lemma. Is it possible to use a variation of this lemma to get 0?, if so how?.

I only need to prove that this integral is indeed 0, then I can derive the Fresnel Integral's value.

Comment: For $r$ small the integral along $C_3$ tends to $0$ as ${r\over \sqrt{r}}=\sqrt{r}.$ For $C_1$ there is a problem as $\sin\theta>0.$ Perhaps changing to the quarter circle $-\pi/2\le \theta \le 0$ may help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc why are we allowed to do that, though? Like, why can i change my contour to be oppositely directed?

Comment: Silly me, $\sin \theta>0$ is OK. Observe that $|e^{iRe^{i\theta}}|=e^{-R\sin\theta}.$ When $R\to +\infty,$ it tends to $0$ uniformly on every interval $[\delta,\pi/2].$ This should help proving that the integral along $C_1$ tends to $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral along $C_1$ can be estimated as follows
$$\left |\int\limits_{C_1}z^{-1/2}e^{iz}\,dz\right |\le \int\limits_{C_1}|z|^{-1/2}|e^{iz}|\,|dz|=R^{-1/2}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin\theta}\, R\,d\theta=R^{1/2}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin\theta}\, d\theta$$
We have $\sin\theta\ge {2\over \pi}\theta.$ Hence
$$\left |\int\limits_{C_1}z^{-1/2}e^{iz}\,dz\right |\le R^{1/2}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-(2R/\pi)\theta}\, d\theta=R^{1/2}{\pi\over 2R}(1-e^{-R})\le {\pi\over 2}R^{-1/2}$$
The integral along $C_3$ is easier as $|e^{iz}|\le 1,$ hence
$$\left |\int\limits_{C_3}z^{-1/2}e^{iz}\,dz\right |\le {\pi\over 2} r\cdot r^{-1/2}={\pi\over 2}r^{1/2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it. After showing those integrals along $C_1$, $C_3$ were 0, all I had to do was solve the integral along the Imaginary axis, along $C_2$, which comes out to be a $\Gamma$-function. The value of the Fresnel Integral follows as a result.